# How to open a serial port with pyserial?

Tags: python, serial-port, ubuntu-10.04, pyserial

I am trying to open a serial port with python. This is on Ubuntu. I import the openinterface.py and enter in this

```
ser = openinterface.CreateBot(com_port = "/dev/ttyUSB1", mode="full")
```

I get an error saying "unsupported operand types for -: 'str' and 'int'" I tried the same call with single quotes instead of double, and with no quotes at all.

How can I fix this? Or is there an alternative function to use? I only know the basics of Python so maybe its some small syntax thing I am not noticing? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page in Russian](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/hard/irobot/irobot.html), there's a bug with the `openinterface.py` file that tries to subtract one from the port argument. It suggests making this change (removing the `- 1` on line 803) with `sed`:

```
sed -ie "803s/ - 1//" openinterface.py
```

Either try that, or see if there's an updated version of `openinterface.py`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want if you are using python 3:

```
import serial                             #import pyserial lib

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 9600)   #specify your port and braudrate
data = ser.read()                         #read byte from serial device
print(data)                               #display the read byte
```