# activate data mode for UART

Tags: python, c, avr

I am using a myAVR MK2 board with an ATmega8.

Within the Windows GUI is an option to enable UART connections. These will than be passed to the controller.

Question: How can i enable this mode on linux to use the UART interface on /dev/ttyUSB0 ?

EDIT 1:
i got further and found an ASCII string to send to the Programmer, to enable data mode.
i tried to implement this in python but it's not working... and idea?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial

s = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=19200)
s.write("\xE6\xB5\xBA\xB9\xB2\xB3\xA9d")
```

Comment: Look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234823/how-to-open-a-serial-port-with-pyserial

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the correct drivers to enable UART over USB. The daughterboard appears to have a CP2102 chip on it.

[drivers link](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx)